# Unable to install external tool 'YouSeeu' in sakai lms

Tags: sakai, lti

I tried to install/connect Youseeu tool in sakai throught LTI. But i am not able to find any values for the following fields
1. remote URl.
2. Remote Tool Key.
3. Remote Tool Secret.
If anybody installed youseeu in sakai or any other lms, please help me out how to do that. i search lot regarding with this, but i didn't found any accurate result.
Here is the screenshot https://snag.gy/ZHGerA.jpg.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Youseeu does use LTI (as detailed at: https://www.youseeu.com/d2l/). Typically if it will work with d2l via LTI it will work with Sakai.

However, you'll need to get the values you've highlighted from your contact at Youseeu.

The url will be where the external tool launches to (likely on youseeu's servers). The key and secret will then both encrypt and identify your connection. These values will be unique for each institution and will be generated by Youseeu.